# SyntaxError after adding new model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Hi guys i have a application call demo. In demo, a main scaffold call 'contact'. now i'm trying to add a new model 'address'(with 5 attributes) in 'contact#show'page. Here's my contactcontroller define show

```
def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    @addresses = @contact.addresses.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

And here is where i trying to display 'address' in view/contacts/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
      <% if @contact.addresses.any? %>
      <h3>Addresses (<%= @contact.addresses.count %>)</h3>
      <ol >
        <%= render @addresses %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @addresses %>
      <% end %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(@contact) %> 
<%= link_to 'List', contacts_path %>
```

Here is the view/addresses/_address.html.erb (i've no idea how to show all attributes of address so i just use 'address.all')

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= address.all %></span>
</li>
```

And when i start server and click on 'show' link  machine give me error message like

```
SyntaxError in Contacts#show
ActionView::Template::Error (/media/sf_VM_working/demo/app/views/contacts/show.html.erb:38: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
/media/sf_VM_working/demo/app/views/contacts/show.html.erb:40: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end):
    35: <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(@contact) %> 
    36: <%= link_to 'List', contacts_path %>
  app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:14:in `show'
```

Could anyone tell me where i make mistake please  thank you very much for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an end on your erb template

It should look like this

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <% if @contact.addresses.any? %>
    <h3>Addresses (<%= @contact.addresses.count %>)</h3>
      <ol>
        <%= render @addresses %>
      </ol>
    <%= will_paginate @addresses %>
  <% end %>
<% end %> 
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contact_path(@contact) %> 
<%= link_to 'List', contacts_path %>
```

Note the closing end for the `form_for` block

Comment: Thank you man, it works. btw the first end is for that if on the 2nd line?

Comment: Yes, the erb tags are just containing ruby so if you open up an `if` you have to close it with an `end` same applies for blocks, that is unless you're using `haml` :D.